# How do I remove the light cover from an Indesit I55VM 1110 W Fridge

Tags: repair, refrigerator, appliances

Hi I have bought an almost new Indesit Indesit I55VM 1110 W UK Fridge. Unfortunately the light isn't working. I can't work out how to get the light cover off to try to replace the bulb. It looks different to the manual and  haven't been able to remove it despite much fiddling and pressing of the top/sides etc.

The manual shows a different looking light cover and it's advice hasn't helped. Indesit support say they can't provide any more information than what's in the manual. [image: instructions from manual]

Can anyone please help? Maybe this is the LED model but I'm not sure how I'd work that out?

I also tried popping off the screw caps (only the front cap on mine had a screw under - back two are redundant) and unscrewed the light unit so it swung away from side of fridge. Looks like I could possibly replace the whole unit if I had to, but swinging it out it didn't seem offer any additional ways to remove the light cover.

[image: model details sticker]

[image: light cover that needs removing]

Comment: There's a slot there on the top, right next to the switch. It's  just asking for a wide flat-bladed screwdriver (or better, a butter-knife) to be inserted.

Comment: If that slit to the left of the switch doesn't help even with reasonable force, pull the temperature knob off and look all around the housing for the light, switch and knob to see if there are screws or clips and you can remove the whole thing, or otherwise if the entire inside wall of the fridge can be removed somehow.  The light assembly may be screwed on from the back.

Comment: Incredible.  The manual says to call the help desk and the help desk says to read the manual!

Comment: Yes @SiHa, getting a knife and trying the dark area next to the switch was my first action - unfortunately despite the appearance it isn't actually a slit. I think it is dark because of what is beneath, rather than a slot on the surface.

Comment: Yes @jay613 I removed the screw and hinged the entire assembly off the wall of the fridge, but it didn't help.

Comment: Post a picture of the entire assembly removed from the wall.  Try to clearly show the sides and back.  Maybe the entire assembly is sold as one part.   But I don't know how you would buy that part since the parts diagram doesn't show it.  That part of your problem is truly bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the instructions in the image you posted:

[image: highlighted picture of instructions the OP posted]

Step 2 is to remove the light cover by releasing the claw with a screwdriver. (See green box & green arrow). That green arrow points to the little, bitty claw that you need to push down to release the catch.

**However**, your cover does *not* have the slots in it like the cover in the picture, nor does it have the "Max 5 W" lettering that appears in the picture. Since those slots are to let the heat from an incandescent bulb escape, and you don't have them, it's likely that your fridge has the LED lighting option. The instructions for replacing the LED lighting are highlighted in red in that picture above.

It's likely that only "authorized personnel" are allowed to replace the LEDs because:

1. It tells them how often the LEDs actually die
2. It allows them to charge for a service call
3. It ensures that that the circuit board with drivers, LEDs, etc is replaced properly
4. It allows them to recover the circuit board for a postmortem to see how it failed so they can, hopefully, improve the design for future models
5. They don't have to supply the circuit board the repair parts supply chain available to the public

Do note: If the fridge is "almost new", Indesit *might* be willing to replace the light under warranty even though you're not the original purchaser and the warranty might not be transferable. It's certainly worth asking - the part itself is probably cheap, but the service call to replace it probably isn't.

Additionally: I just noticed that there appears to be a slot on the squared edge of the light cover, closest to the on/off switch. I'd imagine that a screwdriver, gently pushed into that slot and gently twisted would pop the cover off.

I also notice that the on/off switch is off. Since it never hurts to double check the obvious: You have turned the switch on, right?

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan, I suspect that you are right and it doesn't look as pictured because it's the LED version. Yes, that makes sense about the authorised personnel and the cost of the service call. Cheers

Comment: Oddly, the parts diagram shows an optional LED bulb and socket inside of the housing that is pictured in your diagram and there is an LED bulb for sale on the Indesit web site.   But what you have is not that, it is some other thing where the power button and temperature knob and light are not shown in the parts diagram.   There has to be a way to buy and replace that part!

Comment: [They have to sell you the part](https://eandt.theiet.org/content/articles/2021/03/eu-introduces-right-to-repair-rules-for-electrical-goods/).  It's the law.  Although Brexit may not make it UK law, unless the fridge with the undocumented light is sold only in the UK, the part must be available to the European market.  Phone them and threaten them with EU compliance hell if they don't send you a new light for £15 and instructions on how to fix it.  Tell them you are from Trotter Appliance Repairs and you don't want to have to tell all your customers that their machines are irrepairable.

Comment: @jay613 those are good points about Indesit needing to sell me the part. I didn't feel I had the time to do that, so bought an LED Light strip on a motion sensor which sticks to a magnetic plate that came with it. It's been going for several weeks now and hasn't needed charging. It is probably brighter than the original, and I'm happy with this as a solution.